# Error in R code - c50 code called exit with value 1

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-modeling, decision-tree

So, I'm new to machine learning in R. I'm trying the Kaggle Home Depot product search relevance competition in R. 
The structure of my training data set is -

> 'data.frame': 74067 obs. of  6 variables:
>
> $ id           : int  2 3 9 16 17 18 20 21 23 27 ...
>
> $ product_uid  : int  100001 100001 100002 100005 100005 100006
>   100006 100006 100007 100009 ...
>
> $ product_title: Factor w/ 53489 levels "# 62 Sweetheart 14 in. Low
>   Angle Jack Plane",..: 44305 44305 5530 12404 12404 51748 51748 51748
>   30638 25364 ...
>
> $ search_term  : Factor w/ 11795 levels "$ hole saw",". exterior floor
>   stain",..: 1952 6411 3752 8652 9528 3499 7146 7148 4417 7026 ...
>
> $ relevance    : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","1.25","1.33",..: 13 10 13 9
>   11 13 11 13 11 13 ...
>
> $ levsim1      : num  0.1818 0.1212 0.0886 0.1795 0.2308 ...

where `levsim1` is the vector containing Levenshtein similarity coefficients after comparing the search term and product name. The target value is the relevance and I have tried using the C50 package in R for modeling this training set. However once I run this command:

```
relevance_model <- C5.0(train.combined[,-5],train.combined$relevance)
```

(the relevance vector is in the factor format with 13 levels). My computer hangs for about 15 - 20 minutes because of the computations in R, and I later get this message in R:

> c50 code called exit with value 1

I know that this error is common if there are empty cells, however no cells are empty in the data set.

I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong kind of data for this package. If some one could shed light on why I'm getting this error, or what to read up on in terms of how to model this data set, that would be great.

Comment: I'm guessing that `relevance` should be numeric `train.combined$relevance <- as.numeric(as.character(train.combined$relevance))` ?

Comment: According to the syntax of the model, the target should be in the factor format. It was initially numeric, but running the model with numeric gave me an error saying that it should be a factor. Anyway, I feel that I have modeled this data wrongly.